# Is there an equivalent to the C++ pre/postfix operators for use in Python list comprehensions?

Tags: python, list

I writing a function which populates a list of lists of two elements, where the first element is an element from a different list and the second element is a value which increments.

```
def list_of_pairs(seq, start):
    """ Returns a list of pairs """
    >>> list_of_pairs([3, 2, 1], 1)
    [ [3, 1], [2, 2], [1, 3] ]
    return [[i, start++] for i in seq]
```

Is there an equivalent to the C++ postfix operators which can be used? Thanks!

Bonus question: Is it more Pythonic to use the list constructor, than to construct the list using square brackets?

Edit: Here is my current (less beautiful) workaround -

```
def list_of_pairs(seq, start):
    """ Returns a list of pairs """
    >>> list_of_pairs([3, 2, 1], 1)
    [ [3, 1], [2, 2], [1, 3] ]
    return [[seq[i], start+i] for i in range(len(seq))]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to achieve this. Enumerate return the index along with value while iterating over the list of values. And as per your requirement, you need list of `list` as `[val, index + count]`. Below is the sample code to achieve that:

```
>>> seq = [2, 6, 9]
>>> count = 2
>>> [[val, count+i] for i, val in enumerate(seq)]
[[2, 2], [6, 3], [9, 4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same with [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count), calling `next` on the `count` object for each element of the sequence:

```
from itertools import count

c = count(start)
lst = [[x, next(c)] for x in seq]
```

> construct the list using square brackets

That's a *list comprehension*. It's pretty standard and most certainly Pythonic to use list comprehensions for creating lists.

Answer (score 1):

`++` and `--` have been deliberately excluded from Python, because using them in expressions tends to lead to confusing code and off-by-one errors.

You should use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead:

```
def list_of_pairs(seq, start):
    return [[elem, i] for i, elem in enumerate(seq, start)]
```